# HTTP 500 ERROR While Setting Up Local Development Environment Using Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, twilio

I have been following this link: *https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/java/devenvironment* to help me setup a local development environment using twilio, as this should enable me to send and reply to text messages. I have been trying option 2 from the link as option 1 seemed more challenging. After following the steps, I was successfully able to run and compile the HelloWorld.java file. I reach the last step in the instructions and when I type the link in the address bar I get this error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - com/twilio/HelloWorld (wrong name: HelloWorld)

Description: The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

Exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/twilio/HelloWorld (wrong name: HelloWorld)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2496)
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:862)
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1304)
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1169)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:361)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1080)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:75)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:757)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)}
```

I have tried looking at multiple other related questions and tried their solutions with no avail. All the code that I have used is from the link mentioned previously. I tried moving the HelloWorld.class file to multiple different folders but still can't get it to work. I would appreciate any type of help!

Answer (score 0):

You can troubleshoot this.  Start with your webapps/twilio/WEB-INF/web.xml file and find the servlet-mapping matching your url-pattern, which is mapped to your intended servlet.  The example you reference is mapped to the servlet "HelloWorld", which references a servlet-class of "com.twilio.HelloWorld".  From this, most likely under the "/src/main/java" folder under your project, you should expect to find a "com.twilio" package with a "HelloWorld.java" class inside.

If the HelloWorld.java class is located anywhere besides the com.twilio package, your servlet-class will be pointing to the wrong place.

Comment: You can fix this by either moving your HelloWorld.java class into the com.twilio package (creating that package if it doesn't exist) or by changing the "servlet-class" in web.xml to point to same fully qualified name (package location + class name) of your HelloWorld.java file.

Comment: I got it to work!! Except what I did was remove the com.twilio from the "servlet-class" in web.xml so only HelloWorld was left and that seems to have done the trick. Thanks for the help!